# NullPointerException when launching Camera view activity, which kills it instantly

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I get fatal exception every time launching the tutorial app, clearly installed on phone JIAYU J3, from the activity listed below. All needed permissions and api key are added. Gradle builds finish without visionable failures. The issue goes that way: the app launches the main(camera) activity, holds it for about 1 second and crashes.

The trace:

```
10-13 15:44:55.881 10891-10891/es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.l.k

10-13 15:44:55.927 10891-10891/es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.c.aw.a

10-13 15:44:57.240 10891-10891/es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at android.support.v4.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.r.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.c.x.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.c.v.g(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.c.v.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.c.z.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.c.r.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.q$1.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.j$j.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.j$a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.j$a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.j$e.c(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.j$d.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/obj1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cameraTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Map"
    android:id="@+id/btnMap"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="224dp"
    android:layout_height="224dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/reticle"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

    <activity
        android:name="es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant.CameraViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_camera_view">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant.MapsActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="es.esy.kkaun.procrastinant.CameraViewActivity" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***api key added***" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


</application>
```

Butched activity lifecycle code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout. activity_camera_view);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setupListeners();
    setupLayout();
    setAugmentedRealityPoint();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myCurrentAzimuth.start();
    myCurrentLocation.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    myCurrentAzimuth.stop();
    myCurrentLocation.stop();
    super.onStop();
}
```

And finally full activity code:

```
public class CameraViewActivity extends Activity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnLocationChangedListener, OnAzimuthChangedListener, View.OnClickListener {

private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private boolean isCameraviewOn = false ;
private MObject mPoi;

private double mAzimuthReal = 0 ;
private double mAzimuthTeoretical = 0 ;


private static final double DISTANCE_ACCURACY = 20 ;
private static final double AZIMUTH_ACCURACY = 10 ;

private double mMyLatitude = 0 ;
private double mMyLongitude = 0 ;


public static final double TARGET_LATITUDE = 27.590377 ;
public static final double TARGET_LONGITUDE = 14.425153 ;


private MyCurrentAzimuth myCurrentAzimuth;
private MyCurrentLocation myCurrentLocation;

TextView descriptionTextView;
ImageView pointerIcon;
Button btnMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout. activity_camera_view);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setupListeners();
    setupLayout();
    setAugmentedRealityPoint();
}


private void setAugmentedRealityPoint() {
    mPoi = new MObject(
            getString(R.string. p_name ),
            TARGET_LATITUDE, TARGET_LONGITUDE
    );
}

public double calculateDistance() {
    double dX = mPoi .getPoiLatitude() - mMyLatitude;
    double dY = mPoi .getPoiLongtitude() - mMyLongitude;

    double distance = (Math. sqrt(Math.pow (dX, 2 ) + Math.pow(dY, 2 )) * 100000 );

    return distance;
}

public double calculateTeoreticalAzimuth() {
    double dX = mPoi .getPoiLatitude() - mMyLatitude;
    double dY = mPoi .getPoiLongtitude() - mMyLongitude ;

    double phiAngle;
    double tanPhi;
    double azimuth = 0;

    tanPhi = Math.abs (dY / dX);
    phiAngle = Math.atan (tanPhi);
    phiAngle = Math.toDegrees (phiAngle);

    if (dX > 0 && dY > 0) { // I quater
        return azimuth = phiAngle;
    } else if (dX < 0 && dY > 0) { // II
        return azimuth = 180 - phiAngle;
    } else if (dX < 0 && dY < 0) { // III
        return azimuth = 180 + phiAngle;
    } else if (dX > 0 && dY < 0) { // IV
        return azimuth = 360 - phiAngle;
    }

    return phiAngle;
}

private List<Double> calculateAzimuthAccuracy( double azimuth) {
    double minAngle = azimuth - AZIMUTH_ACCURACY ;
    double maxAngle = azimuth + AZIMUTH_ACCURACY ;
    List<Double> minMax = new ArrayList<Double>();

    if (minAngle < 0)
        minAngle += 360;

    if (maxAngle >= 360)
        maxAngle -= 360;

    minMax.clear();
    minMax.add(minAngle);
    minMax.add(maxAngle);

    return minMax;
}

private boolean isBetween( double minAngle, double maxAngle, double azimuth) {
    if (minAngle > maxAngle) {
        if (isBetween( 0, maxAngle, azimuth) && isBetween(minAngle, 360 , azimuth))
            return true ;
    } else {
        if (azimuth > minAngle && azimuth < maxAngle)
            return true ;
    }
    return false;
}

private void updateDescription() {

    long distance = ( long ) calculateDistance();
    int tAzimut = ( int ) mAzimuthTeoretical ;
    int rAzimut = ( int ) mAzimuthReal ;

    String text = mPoi.getPoiName()
            + " location:"
            + "\n latitude: " + TARGET_LATITUDE + "  longitude: " + TARGET_LONGITUDE
            + "\n Current location:"
            + "\n Latitude: " + mMyLatitude       + "  Longitude: " + mMyLongitude
            + "\n "
            + "\n Target azimuth: " + tAzimut
            + " \n Current azimuth: " + rAzimut
            + " \n Distance: " + distance;

    descriptionTextView.setText(text);
}



public void onAzimuthChanged( float azimuthChangedFrom, float azimuthChangedTo) {
    mAzimuthReal = azimuthChangedTo;
    mAzimuthTeoretical = calculateTeoreticalAzimuth();
    int distance = ( int ) calculateDistance();

    pointerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id. icon );

    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.obj1);
    pointerIcon.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

    double minAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTeoretical ).get( 0);
    double maxAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTeoretical ).get( 1);

    if ((isBetween(minAngle, maxAngle, mAzimuthReal )) && distance <= DISTANCE_ACCURACY ) {
        pointerIcon.setVisibility(View. VISIBLE );
    } else {
        pointerIcon.setVisibility(View. INVISIBLE );
    }

    updateDescription();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mMyLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mMyLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    mAzimuthTeoretical = calculateTeoreticalAzimuth();
    Toast.makeText (this , "latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+ " longitude: "+location.getLongitude(), Toast. LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    int distance = (int) calculateDistance();


    if (mAzimuthReal == 0){
        if ( distance <= DISTANCE_ACCURACY) {
            pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    updateDescription();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myCurrentAzimuth.start();
    myCurrentLocation.start();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    myCurrentAzimuth.stop();
    myCurrentLocation.stop();
    super.onStop();
}


private void setupListeners() {
    myCurrentLocation = new MyCurrentLocation( this);
    myCurrentLocation.buildGoogleApiClient( this );
    myCurrentLocation.start();

    myCurrentAzimuth = new MyCurrentAzimuth( this, this);
    myCurrentAzimuth.start();
}

private void setupLayout() {
    descriptionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cameraTextView );
    btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id. btnMap );
    btnMap.setVisibility(View. VISIBLE );
    btnMap.setOnClickListener( this );
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat. UNKNOWN);
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraview );
    mSurfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback( this );
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder. SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
    if ( isCameraviewOn ) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        isCameraviewOn = false ;
    }

    if ( mCamera != null ) {
        try {
            mCamera .setPreviewDisplay( mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera .startPreview();
            isCameraviewOn = true ;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera. open();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation( 90);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null ;
    isCameraviewOn = false ;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , MapsActivity. class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: NativeStart crashing usually means your layout.xml being faulty. Post that please.

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt, thanks for the tip! I've added .xml file of camera view activity right under the stack trace.

Comment: it looks like you are using proguard for your project. Have you added rules for proguard to not obfuscate the dependencies?

Comment: Can't really find anything, just that RelativeLayout doesn't have an orientation.  Make sure those drawables are existent.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh, do you mean to set the rules in build.gradle file like this: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    } ?

Comment: if in build.gradle you have "minifyEnabled true", then you are using proguard. Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html for more info on how to keep code.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh, yes, just like that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: seems from the jump it was caused by taking unsuitable target SDK, appcompat and play-services versions.